How can I fix a class not found error with Autoloader?
I'm getting a "class not found" error trying to make a Router work:
GET / - Uncaught Error: Class "App\Router" not found in /home/zumb/Documents/HHsite/ALPHA_VERSION/public/index.php:4
Stack trace:
#0 {main}
  thrown in /home/zumb/Documents/HHsite/ALPHA_VERSION/public/index.php on line 4

I don't understand why it can't find my class.
My folders :
public
-index.php
src
-Router.php
vendor
-altorouter
-composer
-autoload.php
views
tableau.php
composer.json
composer.lock
index.php :
<?php
require '../vendor/autoload.php';

$router = new App\Router(dirname(__DIR__) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'views');
$router
    ->get('', 'tableau', '')
    ->get('/blog/category', 'category/show', 'category')
    ->run();

Router.php :
<?php
namespace App;

class Router {

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $viewPath;

    /**
     * @var AltoRouter
     */
    private $router;

    public function __construct(string $viewPath)
    {
        $this->viewPath =  $viewPath;
        $this->router = new \AltoRouter();
    }

    public function get(string $url, string $view, ?string $name = null)
    {
        $this->router->map('GET', $url, $view, $name);
        return $this;
    }

    public function run()
    {
        print "hey";
        $match = $this->router->match();
        $view = $match['target'];
        ob_start();
        require $this->viewPath . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $view . '.php';
        $content = ob_get_clean();
        require $this->viewPath . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'layouts/default.php';

        return $this;
    }
}

composer.json :
{
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "src/"
        }
    },
    "require": {
        "altorouter/altorouter": "^2.0"
    }
}

autoload.php :
<?php

// autoload.php @generated by Composer

if (PHP_VERSION_ID < 50600) {
    if (!headers_sent()) {
        header('HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error');
    }
    $err = 'Composer 2.3.0 dropped support for autoloading on PHP <5.6 and you are running '.PHP_VERSION.', please upgrade PHP or use Composer 2.2 LTS via "composer self-update --2.2". Aborting.'.PHP_EOL;
    if (!ini_get('display_errors')) {
        if (PHP_SAPI === 'cli' || PHP_SAPI === 'phpdbg') {
            fwrite(STDERR, $err);
        } elseif (!headers_sent()) {
            echo $err;
        }
    }
    trigger_error(
        $err,
        E_USER_ERROR
    );
}

require_once __DIR__ . '/composer/autoload_real.php';

return ComposerAutoloaderInitcdc540639fbf1cb4b940a9197d9773c3::getLoader();

I tried "composer dump-autoload".
It works if I just "require" and "use".
How can I fix this?

How could this answer resolve the problem? And why is it duplicated? That question is another topic and does not even use composer.
The index.php is in the global space, so the App\Router should work fine in my opinion. Did you find a way to solve this issue?

I think your setup if fine and the problem is with the composer.
Please try to run this first:
composer dump-autoload;

If this did not resolved your problem, try to uninstall vendor and reinstall composer dependencies. Before you do this, you can make a copy of your vendor directory.
rf -rf /vendor/;
composer i;

Of course if you are not on linux, you can just delete vendor by manually.
The require would fail with fatal error if it could not load the vendor autoloader file, but you should include the file with absolute path instead of relative. This is the best practice.
The script would fail if the PHP script may not be called from the directory where your index.php exist. For example: php public/index.php command would fail. The correct way is:
require __DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php';

